# Testing function with inner function that should be mocked

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jestjs

I have problem with testing this function. I don't know how I can test `checkAuth` when `decode` is mocked.

```
import decode from "jwt-decode";

export const checkAuth = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (!token) {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    const { exp } = decode(token);
    if (exp < new Date().getTime() / 1000) {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // 'Invalid token specified: Cannot read property \'replace\' of undefined'
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

My test doesn't work. It takes original function.

```
import { Auth, AuthAdmin, checkAuth, AppContent, AuthApp } from "./Auth";
import LocalStorageMock from "../../../mocks/localStorageMock";
import decode from "jwt-decode";

global.localStorage = new LocalStorageMock();

describe("auth", () => {
  localStorage.setItem("token", "fake_token_user");
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  it("allows the user to login successfully", async () => {
    const decode = jest.fn(token => {
      return {
        exp: new Date().getTime() / 1000 - 1,
        iat: 1575751766,
        userData: { isAdmin: true, login: "one92tb", userId: 1 }
      };
    });
    //const { exp } = decode(token);

    expect(token).toBeDefined();
    expect(checkAuth()).toBe(true) // It runs original decode function
  });
});
```

Can someone explain to me how to solve that problem?

Comment: What relationship did you expect the const in your test to have to the import in another file? I'd recommend reading e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) method to mock `jwt-decode` module.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import decode from 'jwt-decode';

export const checkAuth = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (!token) {
    return false;
  }

  try {
    const { exp } = decode(token);
    if (exp < new Date().getTime() / 1000) {
      console.log(123);
      return false;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
import decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { checkAuth } from '.';

jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => jest.fn());

const mLocalStorage = {
  _storage: {},
  getItem: jest.fn((key) => {
    return this._storage[key];
  }),
  setItem: jest.fn((key, value) => {
    this._storage[key] = value;
  }),
};
global.localStorage = mLocalStorage;

describe('auth', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('allows the user to login successfully', async () => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', 'fake_token_user');
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    decode.mockImplementationOnce((token) => {
      return {
        exp: new Date().getTime() / 1000 + 1,
        iat: 1575751766,
        userData: { isAdmin: true, login: 'one92tb', userId: 1 },
      };
    });

    expect(token).toBe('fake_token_user');
    expect(checkAuth()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/59233898/index.spec.js (15.687s)
  auth
    ✓ allows the user to login successfully (11ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |    61.54 |       50 |      100 |    61.54 |                   |
 index.js |    61.54 |       50 |      100 |    61.54 |     6,12,13,16,17 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        17.8s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59233898